# Spring Boot + RabbitMQ: how to convert received object using convertSendAndReceive() method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

How can I deserialize a message using convertSendAndReceive() method? It gives me `NullPointerException` due to not being able to find the required class for deserialization in another package. Packages are marked in the code.

**Listener receives and sends messages normally**

```
package org.dneversky.user;

@EnableRabbit
@Component
public class TestListener {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestListener.class);

  @Autowired
  private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  @RabbitListener(queues = RabbitMQConfig.RECEIVE_QUEUE)
  public void doGet(UserReplyMessage message) {
    logger.info("Received message: {}", message);
    UserReplyMessage response = new UserReplyMessage();
    logger.info("Sending message: {}", response);
    rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(RabbitMQConfig.RPC_EXCHANGE, 
RabbitMQConfig.REPLY_QUEUE, response);
  }
}
```

**Configuration of the listener**

```
package org.dneversky.user.config;

@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

  public static final String RECEIVE_QUEUE = "rpc_queue";
  public static final String REPLY_QUEUE = "reply_queue";
  public static final String RPC_EXCHANGE = "rpc_exchange";

  @Bean
  public TopicExchange rpcExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(RPC_EXCHANGE);
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue receiveQueue() {
    return new Queue(RECEIVE_QUEUE);
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue replyQueue() {
    return new Queue(REPLY_QUEUE);
  }

  @Bean
  public Binding receiveBinding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(receiveQueue()).to(rpcExchange()).with(RECEIVE_QUEUE);
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
  }
}
```

**Sender sends a message normally, but it can't to deserialize returning message**

```
package org.dneversky.gateway.servie.impl;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);

  @Autowired
  private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

  public UserPrincipal getUserByUsername(String username) {
    UserResponse message = new UserResponse(username);
    logger.info("Sending created message: {}", message);
    UserResponse result = (UserResponse)     rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(RabbitMQConfig.RPC_EXCHANGE, RabbitMQConfig.RPC_QUEUE, message);
    logger.info("Getting response: {}", result);

    return null;
  }
}
```

**Configuration of the Sender**

```
package org.dneversky.gateway.config;

@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

  public static final String RPC_QUEUE = "rpc_queue";
  public static final String REPLY_QUEUE = "reply_queue";
  public static final String RPC_EXCHANGE = "rpc_exchange";

  @Bean
  public Queue rpcQueue() {
    return new Queue(RPC_QUEUE);
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue replyQueue() {
    return new Queue(REPLY_QUEUE);
  }

  @Bean
  public TopicExchange rpcExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(RPC_EXCHANGE);
  }

  @Bean
  public Binding binding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(replyQueue()).to(rpcExchange()).with(REPLY_QUEUE);
  }

  @Bean
  public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setExchange(RPC_EXCHANGE);
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyAddress(REPLY_QUEUE);
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(6000);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());

    return rabbitTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
  }

  @Bean
  public SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(REPLY_QUEUE);
    container.setMessageListener(rabbitTemplate(connectionFactory));
    return container;
  }
}
```

**Error log**

> 2022-05-22 17:12:31.344 ERROR 16920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [org.dneversky.user.model.UserReplyMessage]] with root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dneversky.user.model.UserReplyMessage
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, you are sending a `UserResponse` to the listener (according to what I see), but the listener receives a `UserReplyMessage`. For the sender you should be getting a `UserReplyMessage` and not a `UserResponse`. Your code hence doesn't make sense. You are also using Spring Boot so why all the manual configuration instead of using the Spring Boot configured instances.

Comment: @M.Deinum I can't use UserReplyMessage in the Sender because it's in another application (module). That is the problem of appearing the error.

Comment: Please read... Your code simply doesn't make sense, you are sending a `UserReplyMessage` and expect a `UserResponse`. If you wnat something else you need to properly configure your `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` to tell it what to use for a certain type header `__TypeID__` and you need to specify (on your client) what you want to use as a mapping. By default the value will be used as is to instantiate a class. The same actually applies to the server side unless that has the different class.

Comment: Described solution there: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412644/spring-boot-rabbitmq-how-to-convert-received-object-using-convertsendandrecei/1412904#1412904

Answer (score 1):

by default, the producer set the `_TypeID_` header as the class name used for the serialization of the object

then consumer uses `_TypeID_` header to know the class that should use to convert the JSON to java instance

you use two different classes to serialize and deserialize the object and you have to configure the converter

Answer (score 0):

inside your `replyContainer` I couldn't see your `messageConverter` bean. In default it uses java objects to send and receive messages without converting them into human readable json.

```java
@Bean
 public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory customListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                               MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter) {
   SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
   factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
   factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter);
   return factory;
}
```

for your consumer;

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitConstants.YOUR_QUEUE_NAME, containerFactory = "customListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessage(@Valid YourEvent YourEvent){
 //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Listener class, you need to add this line to bind your message converter

```
    @Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory jsaFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                              SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
}
```

Also, in the TestListener class, you should replace this line

```
@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitMQConfig.RECEIVE_QUEUE)
```

with this one

```
@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitMQConfig.RECEIVE_QUEUE,containerFactory="jsaFactory")
```